# Looping pthreads that do 1 task at a time (C++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

For example if I know I am going to have to do something 10 times and only one thread can do 1 thing before it terminates.

Could I do something like:

```
  int nthreads = 10;
  pthread_t threads[nthreads];

  for(int p = 0; p < nthreads; p++)
  {
     pthread_create(&threads[p], NULL, myFunc, (void *) x);
  }

  for(int p = 0; p < nthreads; p++)
  {
     pthread_join(threads[p], NULL)
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: Please change this into a small program and try it. If your small program works, then post it as an answer to your own question. If you try for a while and can't get it to work, then please update your question to include the code that you tried and what errors you are getting.

Comment: Does the overhead of creating and maintaining many threads justify creating them?  Generally, the execution time of a thread (or sum of its execution times) should exceed the execution time to create the thread.